Copy happened when pass char * to string?
I need to call a function, whose parameters are type string.
I thought std::string is a good choice, because it provide a lot of interface.
But recently, I found there is a copy happened when i pass char * to const std::string &.
here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
         
using namespace std;
         
void test_string(const std::string & s) {
  printf("%p\n", s.data());
}        
         
int main() {
  char aa[] = "asd";
  test_string(aa);
  printf("%p\n", aa);
}

As the above code shows, I can pass std::string and char [] to my function test_string.
And my arg type is const std::string &, I thought it would be no copy happened.
But the output shows the address is different, I think the function construct a tempory variable string, which copy from my char [] one by one. which is not neccessary.
Is this a bad usage (pass char[] to std::string)? Is there any good advice to avoid copy?

Yes, when std::string is constructed from aa (which is not a std::string), a copy is made. If you pass a std::string to begin with (i.e. if aa was a std::string), it will be done without a copy.

You have two different "objects": First it's the array aa in the main function; Then it's the completely independent (and temporary) object that s references in the test_string function. Why did you think that both pointers would be the same?

"...think the function construct a tempory variable string,..." it does.  Perhaps use std::string_view as the parameter type - constructor (4) will be the one you want.

@Someprogrammerdude i think it would be great, if the string just revise it's data() pointer to the aa address (just one pointer copy cost)

@kevinh std::string owns the memory (containing the string), this would cause problems when it goes out of scope and tries to delete memory it is not responsible for.  std::string_view does not own the memory.

But that's not always possible... It's more about ownership of the data. If the std::string object didn't have full and complete ownership, how would it be able to handle all its own memory management for that data? How would it know which data needs to be deallocated and which should not? What if you make multiple copies? What if you try to modify the string, and it uses a pointer to a (constant) string literal?

Can we pass a char* to const string&? and Passing a char array to a function that expects a const std::string reference

A std::string is modifiable.  Modifying it would be a disaster if it did not have a copy of the data.

Reopened because the dupes only deal with what happens when a char* or char[] is passed for a string const &, whereas here the OP is open to changing the API to avoid a copy (to which the best solution is to use string_view).

@wohlstad Just because OP is open something doesn't mean it isn't a dupe. The question was incorrectly reopened. Just add the answer in the dupe, deleting it from here.

aa is a char array, not a std::string, and so a temporary std::string object is constructer to be passed by reference (as s) into test_string.
When this temporary object is constructed a copy is made (a std::string always owns the data).
If you change aa to be a std::string, no copy will be done and it will be passed by reference.
Alternativly change test_string to accept a std::string_view. A std::string_view does not make a copy when it is constructed (it is just a non-owning view into an existing string and can be constructed from a char array as well as from another std::string).
As all view types (which ar lightweight), you should by default pass std::string_view by value.
This article explains it in more details: Three reasons to pass std::string_view by value.

So, Can I say replace all const std::string & with const std::string_view & is a easy and safe improvement?

You don't need even to use a reference. string_view is very light-weight and usually passed by value. See this about passing view types by value. Added an update about it to the answer.


I thought std::string is a good choice, because it provide a lot of interface.

It's a good choice, so why don't you use it consistently in all cases?
Spare copy is because you are using two data types, so you have to pay for the conversion.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
         
using namespace std;
         
void test_string(const std::string & s) {
  printf("%p\n", s.data());
}        
         
int main() {
  std::string aa{"asd"};
  test_string(aa);
  printf("%p\n", aa.data());
}

https://godbolt.org/z/5PYzroMMP

It will still make unecessary copies, consider using std::string_view and std::print instead. Side note : avoid using using namespace std;. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/efbe1aa1n

I do not see any unnecessary copies, most likely because I am struggling to find even one copy in this small snippet of code. Edit: I do not see using a char* as a requirement

But there is a copy from the string literal (code segment) to the std::string object (data segment). https://godbolt.org/z/bToM6nc9a (lines 31-33 setup the call to the constructor of std::string which will then copy the const string to the std::strings member data). (Luckily it will use SSO so no dynamic memory allocation yet)
